# ESP8266 POST request to Firebase Cloud HTTP Function returns Error 500 Could not handle the request

Tags: json, post, google-cloud-functions, esp8266

It works fine with Postman but gives me an error when I try it through my ESP8266. Here is the code for the ESP8266:

```
if(buttonState == HIGH) //send notification when button pressed
  {
    HTTPClient http;
    WiFiClientSecure client;
    client.setInsecure();
    //client.setFingerprint("A5:D4:06:4C:2A:4B:46:CD:C4:A5:51:7F:4C:F6:62:92:60:90:FD:37");
    http.begin(client, notifUrl);
    http.addHeader("Content-Type", "Content-Type: application/json"); 
    int httpResponseCode = http.POST(input);
    if(httpResponseCode>0)
    {
      String response = http.getString();  //Get the response to the request
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);   //Print return code
      Serial.println(response);           //Print request answer
    } 
    else 
    {
      Serial.print("Error on sending POST: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
      http.end();
    }
    delay(1000);
  }
```

And here is the Firebase Cloud Function:

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

  // Check for POST request
  if(req.method !== "POST"){
    res.status(400).send('Please send a POST request');
    return;
    }

    console.log(req.body);

    var message = {
        data: {
          title: 'Someone is at the door',
          body: 'Always check who it is before unlocking your door :)'
        },
        android: {
          priority: 'high',
        },
        token: req.body.token
      };

    // Send a message to the device corresponding to the provided
    // registration token.
    admin.messaging().send(message)
        .then((response) => {
            // Response is a message ID string.
            console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
            res.status(200).send('Message sent successfully');
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log('Error sending message:', error);
            res.status(500).send("Error sending message");
        });
});
```

Note the `console.log(req.body)` in the Cloud Function. I can see the log when trying with Postman but when trying with the ESP chip the function doesn't even reach till the `console.log` line and just says function exited with status 'crash' in the logs.

I am pulling my hair out here trying to figure out what is going wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Try to strip away everything you don't really need.

Comment: @MarcelStör I have re-read/re-wrote the whole code. Nothing works...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here must be because you are sending a wrong HTTP `Content-Type` header.
You are sending `Content-Type: Content-Type: application/json`, instead of `Content-Type: application/json`, I guess Firebase doesn't like it too much!

In your code it should then be:

```js
http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
```